# Usé python y opencv para detectar el color de figura y hacer el conteo de estas, pero parece que en mi código algo salió mal

Tags: python, opencv

Usé python3 y opencv2 para detectar el color de figura y hacer el conteo de estas, pero parece que en mi código algo salió mal, no sé a que se deba pero de primer momento funcionaba bien y solo en momentos daba error ahora no deja de dar error y por lo mismo ya no he podido realizar la ejecución.

¿alguien puede ayudarme?

El compilador de python3 me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "op2.py", line 37, in <module>
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

En este caso mi código es el siguiente donde he importado la librerias de random, opencv2 y numpy:

```
        import cv2
        import numpy as np
        import random
        
        colors = ['red','blue','green']
        colorsRGB = {'red':(0,0,255),'blue':(255,0,0),'green':(0,255,0)}
        nred = 0
        nblue = 0
        ngreen = 0
        tiempo = 0
        ball_color = ''
        aux_ball_color = ''
        
        color_dist = {'red': {'Lower': np.array([0, 60, 60]), 'Upper': np.array([6, 255,255])},
                      'blue': {'Lower': np.array([100, 80, 46]), 'Upper': np.array([124, 255,255])},
                      'green': {'Lower': np.array([35, 43, 35]), 'Upper': np.array([90, 255,255])},
                      }
        
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cv2.namedWindow('Detector de cuadros (rojo, azul, verde)', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        
        #while cap.isOpened():
        while(1):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                if frame is not None:
                    gs_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)                     # Desenfoque gaussiano
                    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(gs_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)                 # Convertir a imagen HSV
                    erode_hsv = cv2.erode(hsv, None, iterations=2)                   # Corrosión Dilución gruesa
        
                    if aux_ball_color == '':
                        ball_color = random.choice(colors)
        
                    inRange_hsv = cv2.inRange(erode_hsv, color_dist[ball_color]['Lower'], color_dist[ball_color]['Upper'])
                    cnts = cv2.findContours(inRange_hsv.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
        
                    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
                    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
                    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        
                    x = np.int0(box)[2][0]-np.int0(box)[0][0]
                    y = np.int0(box)[3][0]-np.int0(box)[1][0]
                    z = x*y
                    if z >= 50000 or z <= -50000:
                        if aux_ball_color != ball_color:
                            cv2.drawContours(frame, [np.int0(box)], -1, colorsRGB[ball_color], 2)
                            if ball_color == 'red':
                                nred += 1
                            if ball_color == 'blue':
                                nblue += 1
                            if ball_color == 'green':
                                ngreen += 1
                            aux_ball_color = ball_color
                    
                    ball_color = random.choice(colors)
                    print(ball_color)
        
                    cv2.putText(frame, "Cuadro rojo = "+str(nred),[10,25], cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, colorsRGB['red']) 
                    cv2.putText(frame, "Cuadro azul = "+str(nblue),[10,55], cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, colorsRGB['blue']) 
                    cv2.putText(frame, "Cuadro verde = "+str(ngreen),[10,85], cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, colorsRGB['green']) 
        
        
                    cv2.imshow('Detector de cuadros (rojo, azul, verde)', frame)
                    #cv2.waitKey(1)
                    if cv2.waitKey(200) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
                        cap.release()
                        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                        break
                else:
                    print("Sin imagen")
            else:
                print("¡No se puede leer la cámara!")
cap.release()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor revisa la indentación de tu código en la pregunta; ya sabes lo sensible que es python a estas cosas :)  Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Si le pasas a max o min una secuencia (lista, tupla, cadena, etc) vacía ocurre ese error. Tendrás que hacer una condición para tratar de forma especial los casos donde cnts está vacío.

Comment: De que manera podría realizar eso? Ya que estuve tratando con un if pero no me deja de salir el error, en este caso trate de hacerlo de esta manera:

cnts = cv2.findContours(inRange_hsv.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

if max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea).all()!=Empty:
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
else:
c= 1
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)

Comment: Perdón por no responder. Recuerda mencionarme así me llega una notificacion. Puedes hacer la condición con if(cnts) que es True cuando hay algo dentro de cnts y false de lo contrario. En el else puedes poner un valor default para c u omitir el frame.

Comment: Enfócate en cuál es la fuente del problema y lo lograrás! Suerte!